# Besides XmlSlurper and XmlParser, is there some other Jenkins pipeline parse xml file method

Tags: xml, jenkins, pipeline

I have a Servers.xml file like below

```
<Servers>
    <Environment id="1" name="Jenkins">
        <Server id="1" ip="192.168.0.1" />
        <Server id="2" ip="10.21.22.30" />
    </Environment>

    <Environment id="2" name="Pipe">
        <Server id="1" ip="192.10.2.77" />
        <Server id="2" ip="122.30.45.99" />
    </Environment>

</Servers>
```

I want to change value of ip according to Environment tag `name`.
I google some answer, but most of them are using `XmlSlurper` or `XmlParser`, unfortunately both of them are not permitted in my Jenkins pipeline and I got

```
Scripts not permitted to use new groovy.util.XmlSlurper. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
```

My question is that besides `XmlSlurper` and `XmlParser`, **is there some other method that can parse xml file  in pipeline**?

I don't have the permission to permit the above two method.
I don't have permission to download plugins either.

Thank you!

I tried

```
def fileContent = readFile xmlFile
// def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(fileContent)
// def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(fileContent)
xml.Environment.each {...}
```

and

```
@NonCPS
String extractFromXml(String xml) {
    def node = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
    return node
}
```

all the above i got

```
Scripts not permitted to use new groovy.util.XmlSlurper. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
```

Now I don't want to use XmlParser or XmlSlurper, so I wander is there some other way to parse xml file in pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

At last I used powershell script to do this.

```
withEnv(["param=$param", "param2=$param2"]){
powershell '''
    [xml]$xmlContent = Get-Content ./path/file.xml
    foreach ($endpoint in $xmlContent.node.endpoint) {
        if($endpoint.name -eq "$env:someVar"){
            $lines = get-content ./path/file.xml
            $lines | foreach-object {$_ -replace $endpoint.attribute, "replace content"} | set-content ./path/file.xml
        }
    }
'''}
```